# why is ggplot2 geom_col misreading discrete x axis labels as continuous?

Tags: ggplot2, x-axis, geom-col

Aim: plot a column chart representing concentration values at discrete sites

Problem: the 14 site labels are numeric, so I think ggplot2 is assuming continuous data and adding spaces for what it sees as 'missing numbers'. I only want 14 columns with 14 marks/labels, relative to the 14 values in the dataframe. I've tried assigning the sites as factors and characters but neither work.

Also, how do you ensure the y-axis ends at '0', so the bottom of the columns meet the x-axis?

Thanks

Data:

```
Sites: 2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
Concentration: 10,16,3,15,17,10,11,19,14,12,14,13,18,16
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions in one with two pretty straightforward answers:

**1. How to force a discrete axis when your column is a continuous one?** To make `ggplot2` draw a discrete axis, the data must be discrete.  You can force your numeric data to be discrete by converting to a factor.  So, instead of `x=Sites` in your plot code, use `x=as.factor(Sites)`.

**2. How to eliminate the white space below the columns in a column plot?** You can control the limits of the `y` axis via the `scale_y_continuous()` function.  By default, the limits extend a bit past the actual data (in this case, from 0 to the max Concentration).  You can override that behavior via the `expand=` argument.  Check the documentation for `expansion()` for more details, but here I'm going to use `mult=`, which uses a multiplication to find the new limits based on the data.  I'm using `0` for the lower limit to make the lower axis limit equal the minimum in your data (`0`), and `0.05` as the upper limit to expand the chart limits about 5% past the max value (this is default, I believe).

Here's the code and resulting plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  Sites = c(2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
  Concentration = c(10,16,3,15,17,10,11,19,14,12,14,13,18,16)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(Sites), y=Concentration)) +
  geom_col(color="black", fill="lightblue") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=expansion(mult=c(0, 0.05))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]